# Does "no more than two" mean I can choose just one?

Tags: meaning

This is the question:

"Evaluate the representation of... in no more than TWO of the following books: ....." (the "TWO" is actually capitalised in the document)

Without thought, I just automatically understood this as "you can choose just one book, or two books, but two is the absolute max" but now I'm worried this might possibly mean I HAVE to choose TWO books and focusing on just one is not enough/ not allowed???? Especially since they capitalised the word "TWO" ...

(I am stressing out because this is an essay question and I've already started...)

Comment: You are being asked to generalize, and they limit you to two books. The implication is that you would use more if you could. Further thought suggests you should try to use two, instead of one, if you can, and add common ideas without attribution, all to show you understand the topic thoroughly. They're also testing your choice of initial two. Choose two contrasting books to start with, and you can spend the rest of the essay discussing their differences.

Comment: Why not just ask your instructor? I'm guessing they don't want you using ELU for help anyway.

Comment: Logically, you could write about zero books and be following the rules, but you probably won't get a good mark.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the many cases in which taking pragmatics into account may lead to a different understanding from analysing something in terms of semantics alone.

'No more than two' logically entails that discussing only one of the books is perfectly OK. So far as semantics is concerned, there is nothing more to say.

It is, however, possible, but by no means certain, that the person who wrote the instructions was thinking along the following lines:

> Other things being equal, good students will be eager to show their knowledge by discussing as many books as is feasible. To make the task manageable, we will specify the upper limit. We won't bother specifying the lower limit, because we know that, once the upper limit is stated, the enthusiasm of good students will lead them to get close to it. Any student who would be even thinking about what the minimum is, would be approaching the task in the wrong spirit.

**If** one has a reason to think that something like this was on the mind of the person who wrote the instructions, then one will want to discuss two books, notwithstanding that the instructions do not logically entail that one must. Nobody on this site can, however, know whether the person who wrote these instructions was thinking this way, or intended the instructions to be taken at face value. That is not a matter of English language, but of the culture of a particular educational institution, and perhaps just of the practices of a particular instructor.

Incidentally, while it is difficult to be sure how to interpret the instructions in this case, without knowing the surrounding circumstances, there are contexts in which it is very clear that specifying the maximum conversationally implicates (even though it doesn't logically imply) that one should get close to the maximum. If one is told 'write an essay of no more than 1,000 words' it is fairly clear that an essay of 200 words will not get high marks.

Comment: Good point, but I'd say 'no more than two' doesn't frown on a choice of just one in the same way that 'using no more than 1000 words' does on using 200.

Comment: There is nothing **semantically** saying that you cannot choose just one book. How the setters of the question will react to this is another matter, and is entirely outside the scope of language.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, agreed; the 1,000 words example was introduced precisely to show that the implicatures of this kind, which are unclear in the OP's case, can be clearer.

Comment: @DJClayworth, I am unclear as to what the point of your comment is. Is there any aspect of the answer that you disagree with?

Comment: My point is that in terms of English grammar and semantics "no more than two" clearly and unequivocally means "zero, 1 or 2". Deducing anything about the acceptability of "1" is absolutely nothing to do with English and is to do with expectations around examiners and exams - I.e. off topic.

Comment: ... I disagree, @DJ. Pragmatics, how the language is _usually_ used, often looking at seemingly illogical accepted senses, is certainly on-topic here. Admittedly, where many disagree on allowable meanings, the question may well be located in the POB morass.

Answer (score 1):

You can't always use a math equation to parse English, but this one works.

> X is the number of books.
> X "no more than 2" is X <= 2.

Assuming there are no negative numbers of books, strictly speaking you can do 0, 1, or 2 so far. Since you are being asked to evaluate something, it's hard to imagine 0 is an acceptable answer. That leaves 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0):

"No" here is a *degree modifier* modifying "more." It specifies *how many* more than two you can take; the answer is "none." So the meaning is: the number of books you take must not be greater than two.